# Why should any unit test method in C# be void and why are other return types not detected as test?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

```
[CodedUITest]
public partial class UIMap
{
[TestMethod]
public static bool? TestMethod1()
{
//code
}
}
```

This method "TestMethod1" does not show up on Test Explorer. Why?

Comment: Test methods must be public instance methods that are either void or returns `Task` for it to be discoverable by most test runners

Comment: Haven't tried that. But when I make it void. It sure shows up on Test Explorer.
The framework im working on demands methods to be in bool?

Comment: @Niveditha The framework you are using here is the MSTest framework, which definitely *doesn't* require methods to return bool? What is the other framework you are talking about?

Comment: Say there is one main test method 'AutomationTest' that is of type void and subsequently calling these smaller test methods that aren't shown in Test Explorer. 

Would it initiate a new instance of msTest or there is only one instance of msTest created for the main 'AutomationTest' ?

Comment: What do you expect the test framework to *do* with the return values? Anything that can be said about a final value and is part of the test ought to be `Assert`ed (or moral equivalent) within the test

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You will need to clarify what is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever These test methods are now called from another class that checks its condition and later performs the logging. So, there is no assertion within the method.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is dependent on test framework. In some frameworks (not MSTest) the expected value can be specified using an attribute and it can be compared to the return value.

Comment: @Nkosi Currently, the tests are running with one main automationTest calling off the other tests, that means a single instance on msTest.

My aim is to create a new instance of msTest when each of these smaller tests are invoked. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Microsoft's unit test framework:

> **Test method requirements**
>
> A test method must meet the following requirements:
>
> - The method must be decorated with the [TestMethod] attribute.
> - The method must return void.
> - The method cannot have parameters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't mention returning `Task`.

Comment: @FCin Task is the async version of void.

Comment: @Nkosi indeed, but it should still mention it IMO; I'm with FCin here :)

Comment: @Nkosi It is, but these requirements are meant for programmers, so it would seem reasonable to point out all possible types 
independently of how the language handles it later.

Comment: @FCin Noted. Agreed.